# Xcode 7 - Getting "The application does not contain a valid application-identifier entitlement." when trying to run the app on a device with iOS 9

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode7

Doing some tests with the new Xcode 7 beta, created a brand new iOS app, I get the following error when trying to run it on an iPhone 6 with iOS 9 beta.

> The application does not contain a valid application-identifier entitlement.

I have selected my Development Team on the target General settings and I have agreed to the updated license agreements on the Apple Developer portal.

Comment: I created a new project with Xcode 7 and it started working.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error. Removing the app from my iPhone and running again worked for me.